# NSRegularExpression forming a search parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, ios7, nsregularexpression

I am new to Regular Expressions and need some assistance. I have a search feature in my app which currently only allows for a single keyword to be used in the search call. I need a way to format something like this mac and cheese to this mac+cheese. Is there anyway to exclude words which would not be considered keywords? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you searching your data source? It depends on the contents of your data source, the method you use for searching it, etc.

Comment: I am pulling my data from the Yummly API. The API call requires the + format. I need to take what the user inputs into the search field and format it to adhere to the search parameters required by Yummly.

Comment: If I type 'horse radish and cucumber' into the search field, should Yummly receive `horse+radish+cucumber` as the search string?

Comment: Yes, from my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick read through docs tells us that you don't have to worry about keywords. This would be enough:

```
searchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This would remove "and" in "Cumberland" and leave "Cumberl".

Comment: Sorry but that crashed my app, looks like it conflicts with RestKit.

Comment: @TylerMiller47 Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind giving an explanation of what it does exactly, that would be great!

Comment: @TylerMiller47 From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:): *Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.* Basically it replaces all the spaces in the string with a `%20` (and other things) because you cannot send spaces and certain other characters in URLs.

Comment: @TylerMiller47 PS: I suggest you read docs a lot more. This question, as well as your main question, could be answered by yourself on your own if you had just read the docs.

Comment: I'm sure if I would of noticed that Yummly docs mentioned encoding the url, that I would of had no problem with solving it. And yeah the docs are very helpful when you have a general idea where to start. Thank you for the help! hopefully one day I can help someone as well.

Comment: @TylerMiller47 Again, from the Yummly docs: *q: This is the search phrase. Use space to separate words **(url-encoded as either + or %20)**.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of stop words, such as "and", "of" etc. you do not need regex but can proceed as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *searchWords = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].mutableCopy;
searchWords = [searchWords removeObjectsInArray:stopWords];
searchString = [searchWords componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];
```

Comment: It seems duci9y is correct about not needing to worry about keywords. q: This is the search phrase. Use space to separate words (url-encoded as either + or %20). To search for “Onion Soup” recipes append &q=onion+soup or &q=onion%20soup  For example: http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=YOUR_ID&_app_key=YOUR_APP_KEY&q=onion+soup